# How to connect graphenedb / neo4j to play app running on heroku?

Tags: scala, heroku, playframework, neo4j, anormcypher

I have a [Play application](http://www.playframework.com) ([Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org)) setup on [heroku](http://www.heroku.com). Now I want to connect this application to a [neo4j database](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/scala) using the [graphenedb addon](https://addons.heroku.com/graphenedb) for heroku.

I would like to use [AnormCypher](http://anormcypher.org) to interact with neo4j.

Which steps give me such a setup? I would appreciate some example `built.sbt`,`plugins.sbt`,`application.conf` files which allow connecting to neo4j in a `Controller` object.

Comment: I found that this write up was quite informative, if you do not want to use AnormCypher: http://www.kotancode.com/2013/05/14/accessing-neo4j-from-play-framework-2-1-with-web-service-futures/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I guess it was finally time. Here's an example app:

https://github.com/AnormCypher/play-2.3-anormcypher-0.5/

I wasn't particularly creative with the contents, but...
http://play-2-3-anormcypher-0-5.herokuapp.com/

Comment: There is still one minor problem I don't know how to solve:
Locally `GRAPHENEDB_URL` isn't defined, so when I try to run the application locally using 'activator run' it doesn't work as expected. Where should I define this constant, without overriding the variable on heroku? And how? I am sorry for this very basic question..